# WCF service - works locally but returns exception "Bad Data" when published

Tags: c#, wcf, vsto

I am deploying a basic WCF service that executes a query against the database and returns data to be consumed by a VSTO excel addin.

Everything works fine when tested running the service locally, however as soon as the addin is pointed to the published service, I get a 500 error "Bad Data" (that is all that is contained in the return soap packet).

The code on the published end is the same as the local, and I can see the service through the local browser. The published end is another machine on the local network running IIS7.0

client config:

```
      <binding name="zzzServiceBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="10485760" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
              <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" proxyCredentialType="None"
                  realm="" />
              <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
      </binding>
```

and endpoint definitions:

```
  <endpoint address="http://_EDITED OUT_/zzz/zzzService.svc"
      binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="zzzServiceBinding"
      contract="zzzService.IzzzService" name="zzzService_Prod" />
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:51149/zzzService.svc"
      binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="zzzServiceBinding"
      contract="zzzService.IzzzService" name="zzzService_Local" />
```

edit:
one of the methods failing -

```
    [FaultContract(typeof(Exception))]
    public DataTable GetBranchList(DateTime ReportDate)
    {
        try
        {
            return zzzLibrary.GetBranchList(ReportDate);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw LogAndThrow(ex);
        }
    }


    protected FaultException LogAndThrow(Exception ex)
    {
        log.Error("Error in the zzz Service.", ex);
        return new FaultException(new FaultReason(ex.Message));
    }
```

library -

```
    public static DataTable GetBranchList(DateTime ReportDate)
    {
        DbInstance db = GetDBConnection();

        try
        {
            string SQLText = "zzzschema.usp_zzzGetBranchList";
            return db.QueryReturningDataTable(SQLText, CommandType.StoredProcedure, db.CreateParameter("@ReportDate", ReportDate));
        }
        finally
        {
            db.Close();
        }
    }
```

and I know the library routine works because I test it in unit tests, and it works when called from locally running service.

Comment: An HTTP 500 error on a web page or web service is a strong indicator that an unhandled exception was encountered.  Can you show us the code that comprises the service?

Comment: Added one of the service calls to the original question, but again this is the same code that runs on a local service and works. Unfortunately there seems to be a problem with the logging component and I am not getting a log file either :( - another problem I am investigating.

Comment: Maybe that's the source of the unhandled exception.  ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately not :( - I have tested without the logging wrapper and I get the same error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the logging layer around my service allowed me to see a stack trace that was not there with the logging layer.

Turned out to be a config oversight - The stack trace revealed that I had missed a deployment script related to storing database login details.